# Python Regex split by non-alphabet, splitting letters

Tags: python, regex

I need to split a string depending on whether characters are letters or not, splitting all letter characters but keeping any consecutive numbers together.

For example, the string "2a34bc%56def7" should split into
[2, a, 34, b, c, %, 56, d, e, f, 7]

I understand that this will probably need to be done with Regex, but I am not very well versed with using it.
Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried

```
line = re.split('([^a-zA-Z])',line)\
```

but this keeps the letters together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `findall` function instead

```
line = "2a34bc%56def7"
regex = r"\d+|."
print(re.findall(regex, line))

#output
['2', 'a', '34', 'b', 'c', '%', '56', 'd', 'e', 'f', '7']
```

Comment: Use raw string for regex `regex = r"\d+|."` 
 https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#:~:text=The%20solution%20is%20to%20use,character%20string%20containing%20a%20newline.

Comment: @Epsi95 good catch, I used raw string in my testing of the function but forgot to include it in the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,
this is how the regex works:
`\d+` - one or more consecutive digits
`[a-zA-Z]` - a single letter both lower and upper
`[^a-zA-Z\d]+` - one or more consecutive chars that are neither letters nor digits.

```
line = "2a34bc%56def7"
result = re.findall(r'\d+|[a-zA-Z]|[^a-zA-Z\d]+', line)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to regexes is `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> line = "2a34bc%56def7"
>>> import itertools
>>> [x
...     for dec, group in itertools.groupby(line, key=str.isdecimal)
...     for x in ([''.join(group)] if dec else group)
... ]
['2', 'a', '34', 'b', 'c', '%', '56', 'd', 'e', 'f', '7']
```

All you need to do is group the characters by whether or not they're numbers (since you want to group the numbers and split everything else up); then either join the groups into single strings or don't, and put it all into a list.

Answer (score 0):

You could split on any character except a digit `\D` instead of any character except `[^A-Za-z]` and then remove the empty entries:

```
import re

s = "2a34bc%56def7"
res = [m for m in re.split(r"(\D)", s) if m]
print(res)
```

Output

```
['2', 'a', '34', 'b', 'c', '%', '56', 'd', 'e', 'f', '7']
```

---

If you don't want to match spaces, you can match any character except for digits or whitespace chars, or match 1+ digits

```
import re

s = "2a34bc%56def7 abc123"
print(re.findall(r"[^\d\s]|\d+", s))
```

Output

```
['2', 'a', '34', 'b', 'c', '%', '56', 'd', 'e', 'f', '7', 'a', 'b', 'c', '123']
```